# Normal sequences and Montel's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, normal-families

I am currently stuck on an exam question involving normal sequences and Montel's theorem:

1. Give two examples of non-constant normal sequences one in the $(a)$ unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ and one in $(b)$ $\mathbb{C}$.
2. Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of complex numbers satisfying $|a_n|\lt 1$ and an $a_n\to 0$ and
   consider the sequence of holomorphic functions $(f_n)$ in $\mathbb{D}$ deﬁned by:

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\large f_n(z)=\frac{z-a_n}{1-\overline{a_n}z}$

State and justify if $(f_n)$ is normal and whether it satisﬁes the condition of Montel’s
theorem? Explain if $(f_n)$ converges uniformly in $\mathbb{D}$.

Firstly I will state Montel's theorem and then I will write what I have tried so far.

**Montel's theorem**: A family $\mathbb{F}\subset \mathbb{H}(U)$ is normal if and only if it is locally bounded. (Where $U\subset\mathbb{C}$, open, and $\mathbb{H}(U)$ is the space of holomorphic functions on $U$.

My examples for 1. are:

$(a)$ $g_n:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{C}, g_n(z)=\large e^{\frac{iz}{n}}$

$(b)$ $h_n:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}, h_n(z)=\large \frac{z}{n^2}$

Now for $2$. I have chosen to show that $f_n$ has a subsequence that converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{D}$, so let $K\subset \mathbb{D}$ be compact, thus if $z\in K\Rightarrow |z|\le 1$.

I know that since $a_n\to 0$, $f_n(z)\to z$ pointwise.

Now: $\large|f_n(z)-z|=|\frac{z-a_n}{1-\overline{a_n}z}-z|=|\frac{z-a_n-z+\overline{a_n}z^2}{1-\overline{a_n}z}|$

$\large=|\frac{\overline{a_n}z^2-a_n}{1-\overline{a_n}z}|\le \frac{|\overline{a_n}z^2-a_n|}{1-|a_n|}\le \frac{|a_n|(|z|^2+1)}{1-|a_n|}\le \frac{2|a_n|}{1-|a_n|}$

Now we can construct a subsequence:

since $a_n\to 0$ it follows that $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}:\forall j\ge N\,:|a_j|\lt\frac{1}{N}$

So we consider the subsequence $\{f_j\,|j\ge N\}$

Here $|f_j(z)-z|\le\frac{2|a_j|}{1-|a_j|}\lt \frac{\frac{2}{N}}{1-\frac{1}{N}}=\frac{2}{N-1}\to 0$ as $N\to\infty$.

So the subsequence converges uniformly in $\mathbb{D}$, thus $(f_n)$ is normal, and thus by Montel's theorem it is locally bounded, so it satisfies the condition of montels theorem.

Now explain if $(f_n)$ is uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{D}$, this is the part that I am stuck on, and would really appreciate help with.

I would also like clarification if what I have done for the previous parts is at all correct?

Thanks!

There is a third part to the question:

1. Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions from $U$ to the upper half-plane.
   Prove that $(f_n)$ has a subsequence converging uniformly on all compact subsets of $U$
   to either a holomorphic function $f$ or to $\infty$

My approach is to consider the sequence:

$g_n(z)=\large\frac{\frac{f_n(z)}{|f_n(z)|}-a_n}{1-\overline{a_n}\frac{f_n(z)}{|f_n(z)|}}$, here $g_n$ is of the form of part 2. and takes values in the unit disk.

Comment: You have already proven that $f_n$ is uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{D}$. The bound $\frac{2\lvert a_n\rvert}{1-\lvert a_n\rvert}$ is valid on all of $\mathbb{D}$. Yup, all correct.

Comment: I thought that would only prove uniform convergence of subsequences?

Comment: No, you have $a_n \to 0$, hence $C_n := \frac{2\lvert a_n\rvert}{1-\lvert a_n\rvert} \to 0$, and you have $$\lvert f_n(z) - z\rvert \leqslant C_n$$ on all of $\mathbb{D}$ by your computation.

Comment: Ah yes, now you say it, it seems obvious, I've been going round in circles with this for a while. 

And you're sure that everything I've put is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you may need to explain why a locally uniformly convergent sequence of holomorphic functions is normal. But that's pretty obvious, so you may not need to.

Comment: Is that literally because local uniform convergence of the sequence $\Rightarrow$ uniform convergence of a subsequence?

Comment: No, not quite. For normality, you must consider arbitrary sequences whose terms are members of the set $\{f_n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. You can argue that such a sequence must attain some $f_k$ infinitely often or contain a subsequence that is a subsequence of $(f_n)$, but simpler are a) a convergent sequence together with its limit is a compact set, and in a metric space compact = sequentially compact, or b) a locally uniformly convergent sequence is locally bounded.

Comment: I see, so to be clear, our sequence $(f_n)$ converging locally uniformly implies that our set $\{f_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, is locally uniformly bounded, and thus is normal (By Montel).

Comment: Yes. Although for the particular sequence $(f_n)$ given, it might be worthwhile to alternatively point out that all $f_n$ are automorphisms of the unit disk, which of course immediately implies that the sequence is uniformly bounded (not only locally bounded).

Comment: Unfortunately, your $g_n$ is not holomorphic, unless $f_n$ is (locally) constant. Just consider $$g_n(z) = \frac{f_n(z)-i}{f_n(z)+i}.$$ Then $g_n \colon U\to\mathbb{D}$, hence the family is normal, and all you need to show is that if $g_n \to g$ locally uniformly, then $T\circ g_n \to T\circ g$ locally uniformly, where $$T(w) = i\frac{1+w}{1-w}.$$

Comment: Creating 3 new tags with one question seems rather excessive. 
From [FAQ about tags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/128#128): *Try to avoid creating new tags. Instead, check if there is some synonym that already has a popular tag.* It's not easy to keep balance between too specific tags and not having enough tags, but it is always good to search first and to ask yourself, whether newly created tag is not too specific. (Of course, you can disagree with the removal of the tag you've created, and there is possibility for further discussion, if needed.)

Comment: I didn't realise I'd made them, my bad!

Comment: @DanielFischer, how would I use the $T(w)$, to show that one outcome is that $(f_n)$ converges to $\infty$?

Comment: If the $g_n$ converge locally uniformly to the constant $1$, then $f_n$ converges locally uniformly to $\infty$. You can explicitly determine what a small disk around $1$ is mapped to by $T$, namely the complement of a disk in $\mathbb{C}$, and as the small disks shrink to $1$, the images exhaust the plane.

Comment: would $T(w)$ not be $i\cdot\infty$ at $h=1$?

Comment: For all $a\neq 0$, we have $a\cdot\infty = \infty$, so $T(1) = \infty$. When using Möbius transformations, the best point of view is usually to consider the entire Riemann sphere.

Comment: Even if $a$ is imaginary?

Comment: @DanielFischer even if $a$ is imaginary?

Comment: Yes, imaginary makes no difference. There is only one infinite point in $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$, so in that respect it is easier to handle than $\mathbb{R}\cup \{-\infty,+\infty\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer , I've never really thought about it before, so is $i\cdot\infty$ always just $\infty$?

Comment: Yes, everything except $0$ multiplied with $\infty$ produces $\infty$. Since all roads lead to Rome ($\infty$), we don't need to care from which direction we approach it, so if $a\neq 0$ and $z\to\infty$, then $(a\cdot z) \to \infty$, hence $a\cdot\infty = \infty$ for all $a \neq 0$ is natural.

Comment: @DanielFischer
Sorry if this seems dense, but for say $a=-1$, $a\cdot\infty=-\infty$, so what happens with the sign when things are complex?

Comment: The point is that there is only one infinity in $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$. Unlike in the usual real setting, we have $-\infty = \infty = i\cdot\infty = e^{i}\cdot\infty$. It's clear that for $a\neq 0$, the result of $a\cdot\infty$ should be some point at infinity, isn't it? Since there is only one point at infinity, well, it's that one.

Comment: @DanielFischer
Okay, but why is that the case? I mean there only being one $\infty$ in the upper half complex plane? is that because the real axis is not included so the only "pure" infinity is running up the imaginary axis to "$i\cdot\infty$"?

Comment: No, there's only one infinity at all. $\widehat{\mathbb{C}} = \mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$. Stereographic projection gives you a homeomorphism between the plane and $S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{(0,0,1)\}$, and $\infty$ corresponds to the north pole $N = (0,0,1)$. Plane + single point = sphere. Approaching $\infty$ along the real or imaginary axis corresponds to approaching the north pole in the $x-z$-plane or the $y-z$-plane on the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$, it's the same point you approach.

Comment: @DanielFischer
and is this "$\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$" the upper half complex plane?

Comment: No, it's the Riemann sphere. The upper half-plane is usually denoted $\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Than you very much for all of this help, it has been invaluable, my final question in regards to the "$\infty$" is that when we apply the inverse to find the limit of the $f_n$ subsequence, are we not back in the upper complex plane rather than the reimann sphere?

Comment: The upper half-plane is a subset of the Riemann sphere. The $f_n$ take only values in the upper half-plane, so the limit function of a subsequence takes values in the closure of the upper half-plane, where the closure is with respect to $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$ (so $\overline{\mathbb{H}} = \mathbb{H}\cup (\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\})$). If the limit function is not constant, it is an open mapping, hence its values are all in $\mathbb{H}$ then. If the limit function is constant, it can be a finite constant (in $\mathbb{H}\cup\mathbb{R}$) or $\infty$.

Comment: @DanielFischer do you know of any good books to learn about montels theorem, particularly in relation to normal familes?

Comment: Hm, sorry, in the books I have, it's not treated extensively. It's proved, and used to prove the Riemann mapping theorem, and some go on to prove the Big Montel theorem. There's not much discussion of it (but to be fair, I wouldn't know much to say either).

Comment: @DanielFischer, where you consider the map $g:U\to \Bbb D$, my belief is that it maps to the closed unit disk, rather than the open unit disk, is this correct?

Comment: Not sure what you refer to. The only use of $g$ I see is as the locally uniform limit of the $g_n$, and that could indeed be a constant of absolute value $1$. If $g$ is non-constant, it maps $U$ to $\mathbb{D}$, if it is constant, we only know the value is in $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry I meant $g_n:U\to \Bbb D$ in this case is $\Bbb D$ the closed or open disk?

Comment: Unless by "Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions from $U$ to the upper half-plane" you mean the closed upper half-plane, it is the open unit disk. If the $f_n$ are allowed to be real-valued constants, then the $g_n$ may be constants of absolute value $1$.

Comment: Yes I believe, by upper half plane, this includes the real axis.
Also, without the real axis, there could not be uniform convergence to $\infty$ right?